# Round CachedNetworkImage in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

```
new Container(

                  width: 80.0,
                  height: 80.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(

                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: new NetworkImage(widget.profile_picture)))),
```

At the moment I have a NetworkImage however I wold like to have a round CachedNetworkImage instead.

Comment: If you want to use `Container` you can put `Container` inside `imageBuilder` of `CachedNetworkImage` as shown here: (https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/177#issuecomment-510359079)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use

```
ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10000.0),
child: CachedNetworkImage(...))
```

Since CachedNetworkImageProvider is not a Widget, it doesn't work in place of a CachedNetworkImage. Meaning it won't have the placeholder widget option.

Comment: This should be accepted answer since it preserves all CachedNetworkImage functionality.

Comment: @heyab-redda :)

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `CachedNetworkImageProvider` like this:

```
new Container(
    width: 80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: new DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.profile_picture),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
Also, is there any chance to use with it:
placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),  ?

Comment: You can use a FadeInImage and set the CachedNetworkImageProvider as its image. It will provide placeholder and fading options for you.

Answer (score 18):

you should try it

```
ClipOval(
   child: CachedNetworkImage(
       imageUrl: url,
       fit: BoxFit.cover
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `imageBuilder` of the `CachedNetworkImage`:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    placeholder: (context, url) => placeholder,
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => errorWidget,
)
```

In order to have a rounded image, set the width and height to the same value and set the `borderRadius` to half the height.

Comment: this is the correct answer rendering the Container before the image ,

Answer (score 2):

BorderRadius and Border Color

1st way

```
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border.all(color: Palette.greyTextColor),
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),),
                  child:  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
```

2nd way

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                       imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                         width: width,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border.all(color: Palette.greyTextColor),
                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                           image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvider),
                         ),
                       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this to create a circular cached image network with border color

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircularCachedNetworkImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageURL;
  final double size;
  final Color borderColor;
  final BoxFit fit;
  final double borderWidth;

  const CircularCachedNetworkImage({
    required this.imageURL,
    required this.size,
    required this.borderColor,
    this.fit = BoxFit.fill,
    this.borderWidth = 2,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: borderColor,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(borderWidth),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white, // inner circle color
          ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(300.0)),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: imageURL,
              fit: fit,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

usage

```
CircularCachedNetworkImage(
   imageURL: "your image URL in here",
   size: 100,
   borderColor: Colors.green,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed an avatar widget that kept the circular shape whether the CachedNetworkImage was square or not, and was not fixed to one size but used the available space. My solution was this:

```
CircleAvatar(
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: imgUrl,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClipOval instead of ClipRRect

```
 child: ClipOval(
          child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl : url),
 fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me i use following code navigation drawer for display the profile image.

```
Center(
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  width: 90,
                  height: 90,
                  imageUrl:
                      "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1668383210938-0183489b5f8a?q=80&w=2874&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: imageProvider,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  //     placeholder: (context, url) => placeholder,
                  //     errorWidget: (context, url, error) => errorWidget,
                ),
              ),
```